# ResideMenu item disable?

Tags: java, android, residemenu

so i just come here with a problem regarding android i am not able to
disable ResideMenu item here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ResideMenu resideMenu;
    private ResideMenuItem itemLogout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        resideMenu=new ResideMenu(this);
        resideMenu.setBackground(R.drawable.background_img_jpeg);
        resideMenu.attachToActivity(this);
        resideMenu.setMenuListener(menuListener);
        resideMenu.setScaleValue(0.6f);

        itemLogout=new ResideMenuItem(this,R.drawable.icon_logout,"Logout");
        resideMenu.addMenuItem(itemLogout,ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT);
    }
}
```

i want to remove or Disable this menu item on Click

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what library or class you are using but might this helpful `resideMenu.setSwipeDirectionDisable(ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT);`

Comment: .setSwipeDirectionDisable(.....);  Disable only swipe Right or left, but I want to remove or disable only single menu item.  thanks for Answers

Comment: @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == btnSave){
        // i want to dissable here itemLogout
    }
}

Comment: You can create null listener on button save click and reset to          resideMenu.setMenuListener(menuListener);. share your code in your question with detail.